# Bootstrap sidebar and footer not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to add a footer for many web pages developed using jQuery and bootstrap 3. I have written the following script based on [this Bootstrap's example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) to do the job

```
// Default
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('body').append('<footer class="footer">' + 
                               ' © 2015 ABC Company. All rights reserved. | Content for internal use only. | ' +
                               '<a href="mailto:#">Contact Us</a> ' +
                          ' </footer>');
});
```

related CSS

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99FFFF;
  padding-top:5px;
}
```

This work well for all pages except pages with sidebars where the sidebar overlaps the footer like below

[image: overlap of footer and sidebar]

I have tried to fix it  by adding `margin-bottom: 40px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */` to `.sidebar` in CSS. Now it looks like below

[image: white space in bottom of sidebar]

[image: footer in bottom of the page]

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/oaIxSjQvX9)**

How to fix this? I can't add and style individual footer for each page as there are many pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add z-index:600 in your footer's css, will bring your footer on the top of everything.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue forgot about `z-index`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your footer to be displayed in front of other elements on the page. Using the `z-index` CSS property should help with this.